# R OSRM: Error in doTryCatch(return(expr), name, parentenv, handler): object 'res' not found

Tags: r, osrm

Trying to do a simple isochrone using the `osrm` package in R, following this example:
https://rstudio-pubs-static.s3.amazonaws.com/259089_2f5213f21003443994b28aab0a54cfd6.html

`iso1 <- osrm::osrmIsochrone(loc=c(-93.2223, 44.8848),breaks=10)`

Yields the following output to the console.  This occurs whether I try to call the default server  https://routing.openstreetmap.de/ or an internal OSRM server. I assume this is a simple problem, but I haven't seen anything on Google or SO.

````
Error in doTryCatch(return(expr), name, parentenv, handler): object 'res' not found {repeat 8 more times}

Error in UseMethod("st_as_sf") : 
  no applicable method for 'st_as_sf' applied to an object of class "NULL" ```
````

Answer (score 2):

The first error may be related to a limit in the OSRM server configuration that your query exceeds, see osrm-routed options, e.g.:

```
--max-table-size arg (=100)           Max. locations supported in distance
                                        table query
```

Indeed, computing isochrones may require queries for large time/distance tables.

Answer (score 1):

I see maybe 2 problems :

- The CRAN version of `osrm` uses `.onAttach()` to set the server address and the routing profile. Using `osrm::` does not attach the package, so the server is not set. You should use `library(osrm)` to set the server or directly use `osrm.server` and `osrm.profile` arguments in the function.
- But if you tried to use an internal OSRM server you have probably used something like:

  ```r
  options(osrm.server = "https://routing.openstreetmap.de/", osrm.profile = "car")
  ```

  In this case, check the `osrm.profile` argument, in the previous versions "driving" was allowed as profile name but now the only allowed names are "car", "foot" and "bike".

Comment: I had attached via `library(osrm)`, forgot to put that in the snippet.  I verified both profile and server were as you listed.  Same issue.

Comment: Well that's unfortunate. I would suggest to try the dev version of `osrm` (`remotes::install_github("riatelab/osrm")`. If this does not work maybe we should continue this discussion in the [github repo issue tracker](https://github.com/riatelab/osrm/issues) as it could be a bug in the package.

Comment: My mistake - it works when using my personal Windows machine connecting to https://routing.openstreetmap.de, so probably more a company internal issue.